# What icon can I use to represent Facebook share action for iOS?

Tags: icons, ios, ipad, sharing, facebook

I am now working on the interface for iPad app where one of the most frequently used feature is "Share to Facebook".

I am wondering what would be the best way to represent this action. Most of the apps put "Share to Facebook" under the Action button with lots of other action like Email, Add to bookmarks, etc.

I want to simplify it and to make one button which will pull down the popover with text field for users comment/annotation. It will be placed at the "social interaction" panel along with Like and Comment icons (both are standard "thumbs up" and "comment balloon" symbols)

Comment: Simple icon-requests (what's an icon for X) are off-topic as per the [FAQ]; if your question is more about how to represent Share to Facebook on iOS I'd recommend editing your question to be more along those lines.

Comment: If you can't think of a visual symbol to describe something, it's time to use labels.

Comment: If you can edit your question to be about "What icon can I use here" we can reopen it as an answerable question. Your problem is really "how can I represent this in a familiar, usable way", don't narrow your thinking to only icons.

Comment: sorry, guys... I have edited the question. Hope now it fits the guidelines

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading [Facebook share for developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) and use some of the standard icons/buttons available. It's much easier for a user if she recognizes the button from other applications and web pages.

[image: Facebook share buttons and icons]